# Iterate over Controls with LibreOffice Basic

Tags: vba, controls, libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-basic

I'd like to iterate over Controls in a LibreOffice form with Basic.

Basically, I'd like to do what this code does in VBA.

```
Sub parcours_controles_formulaire()
    Dim cControl As Control
    Dim sLog As String
    sLog = "List of controls : " & vbCrLf 
    For Each cControl In FrmExemplesControles.Controls
        sLog = sLog & _
        cControl.Name & _
        " of type " & _
        TypeName(cControl) & vbCrLf
    Next cControl
    MsgBox sLog
End Sub
```

**EDIT :** Here is what I found with Lyrl's help. That's not totally correct yet. I'm not able to get the labels of controls.

```
Sub iterate_forms_controls()
    Dim Dlg As Object
    Dim Controls As Object
    Dim cControl As Object
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim A As String

    DialogLibraries.LoadLibrary("Standard")
    Dlg = CreateUnoDialog(DialogLibraries.Standard.BoiteDeDialogue1)

    Controls = Dlg.Controls

    I = 0
    A = ""
    For Each cControl In Controls
        I = I + 1
        A = A & cControl.getImplementationName()
        'A = A & cControl  ' How to get back the label of cControl here ?
    Next cControl

    MsgBox "There is " & i & " controls in that form !" & A
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this code was tested in OpenOffice.  I believe it will work the same way in LibreOffice.

Controls are located on the drawpage.  If there might be non-control drawpage objects (arrows, shapes, images, etc.) and you want to operate just on controls, you have to iterate through all the draw objects and test each one for being a control:

```
Sub iterate_forms_controls()
    Dim oDP As Object : oDP = ThisComponent.drawpage
    Dim cControl As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    REM The oDP assignment above is for a standard form (a Writer document).
    REM If you are using a Calc document as a form you would instead write:
    REM oDP = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("SheetName").drawpage

    For i = 0 To oDP.Count - 1
    cControl = oDP.getByIndex(i)
        If cControl.supportsService("com.sun.star.drawing.ControlShape") Then
            'Do something
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I looked at the object "cControl" with XRay. Looked through the properties, and nothing looked useful.  I then went to methods and found a method "getModel".  Double-clicked on getModel to XRay that method, and found "Label" with the name I'd given the checkbox.  Woot!  (I've worked with other objects that have certain properties only accessible through a "model"; it's not an intuitive place to look.)

So try this:

```
For Each cControl In Controls
    I = I + 1
    A = A & cControl.getModel.Label
Next cControl
```

Comment: Thanks @Lyrl but that's not exactly what I meant. It helped me to progress and now here is my code. Only two lines remain wrong.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the API name for the label. I recommend using an object inspection tool: they examine the object you give it (here you'd feed it cControl) and return all the object's properties and methods. You can scroll through the properties list and find the API name of the label. Two good ones for Open/LibreOffice are Xray ([link](http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html)) and MRI ([link](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool)) also see this MRI tutorial: [link](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=49294)

Comment: I've tried with Xray. It hasn't helped :(. I'll try MRI later. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with some additional information.

Comment: That's brilliant. We can use `cControl.getModel().Label` on controls which own labels, and `cControl.getModel().Name` on all controls ! Thanks a lot !